How to prove $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{2}{9})^n\frac{(2n)!}{(n+1)!n!)} = \frac{3}{2}$
My problem is to evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{2}{9})^n\frac{(2n)!}{(n+1)!n!}$. After manually calculating, I am observing that the value seems to approach $\frac{3}{2}$. Peculiar, but I have no idea on how to go about proving that.
Some observations:

$\frac{(2n)!}{(n+1)!n!}$ is the $n$th Catalan number.
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{3}{9})^n\frac{(2n)!}{(n+1)!n!}$ diverges to infinity.

I would be astonished if the value of the summation can be calculated.
Thank you!

If you know the generating function of the Catalan numbers, you can substitute in $ x = 2/9$ to show sum $=3/2$, and diverges at $x = 3/9$. There might be other approaches to calculating this, so it might not be a duplicate. (But nothing else comes to mind, and this is the obvious thing to do ...) $\quad$ Here is a way to find the generating function: Prove the generating function for the Catalan number sequence is $f(x) = \frac{1 -\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}$.

@CalvinLin Interesting, I will look if this answers my question.

It does. I learned some good math today. Thank you!

You can use the generating function for the central binomial coefficients:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{2n}n x^n = \frac 1{\sqrt{1-4x}} \text{ for } |x| < \frac 14$$
Now, note that $\frac 1{n+1}\binom {2n}n = \frac{(2n)!}{(n+1)!n!}$. So you can rewrite your sum as follows and integrate:
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n \frac{(2n)!}{(n+1)!n!} = \frac 1x \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\binom{2n}n= \frac 1x \int_0^x\frac 1{\sqrt{1-4t}}dt$$
$$= \boxed{\frac 1{2x}\left(1-\sqrt{1-4x}\right)}$$
For your $x= \frac 29$ you get the "desired" value of $\frac 32$.

This proves it nicely. I think I am astonished. Thank you very much!

You are very much welcome. It's always nice to help people who like maths, too. :-)
